# ip route for two interfaces: I'm confused by order of entries

Tags: ip

```
ip r 
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth01 proto static metric 1000 
default via 10.0.0.1 dev wlan0 proto static metric 2000 
10.0.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.129 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth01 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.120
```

The first two lines suggest the order of priority is `eth01/wlan0`.

The second two lines suggest the reverse.

How are we to read this output?

Comment: Here is my guess. There are two entries for traffic to 10.0.0.0/24. Since they have no metric, they have equal priority; I don't know if the order of the entries has an effect (a very superficial web search indicates it might not). Traffic to other destinations is routed via the lower metric NIC, i.e. eth01 if available; if not, wlan0.

Comment: @berndbausch There is a metric configured and displayed in the output -- in the first two lines. The next two lines seem to ignore the metric.

Comment: You are correct, but this is no different from what I said. Let me rephrase it: The default entries have metrics, the 10.0.0.0/24 entries don't. Therefore, eth01 is the preferred interface for default traffic, and I believe that there is no preferred interface for 10.0.0.0/24.

Comment: @berndbausch Ah. I think see what you're saying now. Not sure I understand completely, 10.0.0.1 is the gateway so all traffic leaving the LAN will go through there? Whereas the 10.0.0.0/24 (LAN traffic) will be directed without preference?

Comment: I suppose (and I am not certain) that the interface is selected when the routing decision is made, i.e. traffic to 8.8.8.8 is sent via eth01, since this is what the routing table entry for the lowest metric contains.